# Pipe output of script to less

Tags: python-2.7, file-io

I have a Python script that has a fair amount of print statements.
Is there a way for me, in my script, to specify the output of the function as a pipe into `less`?

One of the ways I thought to do it was by starting up `less` as a subprocess, getting it's file descriptor, and changing the `stdout` to feed into the `less` subprocess. Is that the right way, or is there an easier way to do so?

Note that this question is out of pure laziness :) - I don't want to have to manually pipe it to `less`, and this script is hosted on more than one machine, so I can't `alias` it easily

Comment: Are you looking for a Python Implementation? Otherwise, what keeps you from using the terminal/bash?

Comment: @Krazor I'm asking about a python implementation, as I updated the question to reflect, I'm lazy and don't want to type `| less` each time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so one possible way to solve this is to print to a file. Since you are on python 2.7 you will have to `from __future__ import print_function`. You can then follow the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) in order to route all output to elsewhere. After that, you can use this file as an arg for a `subprocess.call()` to less.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I was thinking of, except skipping the file and just redirecting `stdout`

Comment: I don't know about any other ways, sorry :(